# Body in API call from httr package

Tags: r, httr

I would like to call my Philips Hue lights from R via the API and httr package. The problem is however that I can't get the `body` right. I'm sure the API works because `GET` calls work fine.

For example, the body in a `PUT` call to turn the lights on and off should look exactly like `{"on":false}`. The call looks like `PUT(url = url), body = body1)`

However, I cannot get this to work in the `body` section from the httr package. I already tried: `body1 <- '{on:"false"}'`
Which returns: `"{on:\"false\"}"`, `body2 <- list(on = "false")` returns `$on [1] "false"` and `body3 <- toJSON(body2)` returns `{"on":["false"]}`.

As you can see none of the above options exactly desired return and they all produce extra punctuation marks. Any idea how I can get exactly `{"on":false}` in the body?

Unfortunately, I cannot provide you with a reproducible example because there is no public sandbox environment available and I don't want everyone to control my lights ;-) However the documentation can be found [here](https://www.developers.meethue.com/philips-hue-api).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `toJSON` from the `jsonlite` package, then you can do

```
library(jsonlite)
PUT("https://url", body=toJSON(list(on = unbox(FALSE))))
```

The `unbox()` will prevent the R vector from being wrapped in the brackets for a JSON array.

Comment: Thanks, this helps to remove `[]`, but I still got the `""` around `false`.

Comment: @jeroen81 Sorry. Missed that part. I've updated the code. Just use a proper R boolean value.